# HTML - Hide and unhide div by display none

Tags: html, css, display

I am trying to make a show & hide `div`. I use the tutorial from `w3schools` (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show) but in this the div is already shown and then you hide it while mine is hidden and then shown. So in the example, I just add `display: none;` to `#myDIV`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    #myDIV {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 50px 0;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: lightblue;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
  </div>

  <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

When I first click the `Try it` button then the `div` doesn't show... Why? From that point on if I reclick it it shows and disappears normally... How can I fix this? Ty

Comment: The div doesn't show because you have `display:none` in your css, change it to block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because first time, `x.style.display` is not defined!

Modify your condition to `if (x.style.display === "none" || !x.style.display)`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    #myDIV {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 50px 0;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: lightblue;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
  </div>

  <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      if (x.style.display === "none" || !x.style.display) {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, it indeed worked. Why it is not defined though? 0_o

Comment: I don't know why this exactly happens, but if you use inline style for `div` this problem does not occur!

Answer (score 0):

Under #myDIV you have set `display: none` remove that line and it will automatically show up